# Quill is not defined when i import from node_modules

Tags: javascript, npm, import, quill

I wanna use quill in my project(laravel)

When i require quill from cdn my code working

but when import from node_modules i got this error :

```
Quill is not defined
```

what can i do?

my code :

```
import 'quill/quill';
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow',
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import Quill using the ES6 Syntax or the CommonJS `require` syntax.

Change the line:

```
import 'quill/quill';
```

to ES6 Syntax:

```
import Quill from 'quill';
```

Or CommonJS with Require

```
const Quill = require("quill");
```

Making the whole thing something like:

```
const Quill = require("quill");
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow',
});
```